# Chrome only updates with jquery.html() when debugging and hitting breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I've got the following snippet in my web page. It's suppose to temporarily change the inner HTML content of a container, when the user clicks a "BUY" button on the page.

```
//////////
 // Add items to basket //
 //////// 
function addToBasket(pageId, itemId, produktNumber, domElem) {
        var tempHtml = $(domElem).html();
        $(domElem).html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
        $(domElem).attr('disabled', true);
        // Update the cart 
        updateCart('/default.aspx?id=' + pageId + '&amp;productid=' + itemId + '&amp;quantity=' + $('#antal_' + produktNumber).val() + '&amp;cartcmd=add', undefined, false, domElem);
        $(domElem).html(tempHtml);
        $(domElem).removeAttr('disabled'); }
```

The second line in the function is only triggered in Chrome when I'm debuging... Anyone out the who has seen a simular problem?

It's works great in IE and FF - so I'm very confused right now...

** EDITED **

Okay... So I've edited the script according to advice I've been given - but the problem remains :( A actualy thought the ajaxComplete should fix it, but it doesn't... **workingElement.html('');** seems to be skipped when running without breakpoints.. And ONLY in Chrome...

```
function addToBasket(pageId, itemId, produktNumber, domElem) {
    var tempHtml = $(domElem).html();
    var workingElement = $(domElem);
    workingElement.html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>');
    workingElement.attr('disabled', true);
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        workingElement.html(tempHtml);
        workingElement.removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    // Update the cart 
    updateCart('/default.aspx?id=' + pageId + '&amp;productid=' + itemId + '&amp;quantity=' + $('#antal_' + produktNumber).val() + '&amp;cartcmd=add', undefined, false, domElem);
}
```

Comment: maybe this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621278/innerhtml-works-in-ie-and-firefox-but-not-chrome) will help you

Comment: Looks like `updateCart` is probably an asynchronous function, so `$(domElem).html(tempHtml);` is going to be executed pretty much straight away; it won't wait until whatever asynchronous action `updateCart` kicks off has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Anthony Grist got it right... The async call was the issue

Answer (score -2):

You need to instantiate jQuery in your function if it is not wrapped already:

```
function addToBasket(pageId, itemId, produktNumber, domElem) { $(function() {

    // Your Code Here

}); }
```

Comment: Why would you need a DOM ready handler inside a function that's almost certainly being called after the page has finished loading?

Comment: Keywords being "almost certainly", you do not know if jQuery is loaded or not.

Comment: No I have access to jQuery, but the fact that it was an async call cased it to be "jumped"