# innerHTML not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I am trying to replace a `div` using `ajax` below code,

```
document.getElementById("htmlText").value = Txt;

var url = 'VideoPlay.jsp?s=' + Txt;

var req;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
req.open('get', url, true);
req.onreadystatechange = callback;
req.send(null);

function callback() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        var msg = req.responseText;
        alert("before");
        document.getElementById("VideoDiv1").innerHTML = msg;
        alert("after");
        frameccount();
    };
};

function frameccount() {
    var C_Frame = $('#C_Frame').val();
    var VideoName = $('#VideoNames').val();
    var f;
    var flashMovie = getFlashMovieObject("myFlashMovie");

    if (C_Frame != 0) {
        var r = confirm("Do you want to Resume");
        if (r == true) {
            alert(C_Frame);
            f = C_Frame;
            flashMovie.GotoFrame(f);
            flashMovie.Play();
        } else {
            f = 0;
            flashMovie.GotoFrame(f);
            flashMovie.Play();
        }
    } else {
        flashMovie.Play();
    }
}
```

this code working fine in firefox but that `innerHTML` not works in chrome.There is no error shows in chrome.even that `alert("before")` and `alert("after");` works in chrome means no error in `innerHTML`.

where i am wrong? how to fix?

Comment: Do you get any error in your console? because the information you've provided is incomplete or rather not useful to solve the issue

Comment: @Mr.Alien check my question now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML works in IE and Firefox, but not Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621278/innerhtml-works-in-ie-and-firefox-but-not-chrome)

Comment: @LiamSorsby i replace the div with <object> tag it contains swf file. it works fine in firefox but in chrome div replaced after confirm box thats why i cant resume my video

Comment: @LiamSorsby actually my problem is in firefox div replaced before confirm box than only my code will take the swf file which is present in the <div>.but in chrome <div> is replaced after all the codes executed inside the confirm box so my resume code is not working.